# what is the optimal cache setting for Grail 2.x app running on Travis CI

Tags: grails, travis-ci

On Travis CI I can specify cached directories:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/

So I've specified following configuration:

```
  cache:
    directories:
    - node_modules
    - ModelCatalogueCorePlugin/target/work/plugins
    - ModelCatalogueCorePluginTestApp/target/work/plugins
    - $HOME/.m2
    - $HOME/.grails/ivy-cache
    - $HOME/.grails/wrapper
```

Yet when I run `./grailsw test-app` lot of dependencies are not retrieved from the cache but download instead.

Are there any other directories suitable for caching I'm missing?